# Nullpointer Exception while trying to add a Node to a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this piece of code to add a Node to a link list:

```
  public class linkedList1 {


public class Node{
        private int item;
        private Node next;

        public Node(){
            next = null;
        }
        public Node(int value, Node _n){
            this.item = value;
            next = _n;

        }

        public Node getNextNode(){
            return next;
        }

        public void setNextNode(Node v){
             next = v;
        }
    }

  private static Node head;

  public  linkedList1(){
      head = null;
  }
  public linkedList1(Node head){
      this.head = head;
  }
  public void setLinkedList(Node n){
  }
  public void addLast(Node n){

      Node currentLast = head;
      Node node;
          while( (node = currentLast.getNextNode()) != null){
          currentLast = node;
      }
      currentLast.setNextNode(n); 
      System.out.println("ADDED");
      }

  public void travers(){
     Node currentLast = head;
      while(currentLast.getNextNode() != null){
          System.out.println(currentLast);
          currentLast=currentLast.getNextNode();
      }
  }
```

my main method does the following ( Keep in mind, I'm not too sure I'm initializing the linked list well):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
  linkedList1 newLinkedList = new linkedList1(head);
  Node second = newLinkedList.new Node(6,null);
  Node head = newLinkedList.new Node(5, second);
  Node third = newLinkedList.new Node(8, null);
  newLinkedList.addLast(third);


  }
```

Its throwing me this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException --> occurs at addLast and then in my method at the while() loop. Any help finding out why?

Comment: What does your `Node` class look like? What does your `linkedList1` class look like? What's the full stack trace of the exception? It looks like you're trying to use `head` before its even declared. Does your main method compile?

Comment: I didnt put it because last time I've been told to just include snippets, which I did. Ill edit it.

Comment: Btw people no need to downvote questions that are made by people trying to learn. This just discourages others to post their question to which they thoroughly TRIED to find an answer. Very saddening to see.

Comment: In general, the code you put in a question should be self contained. The original snippets you provided contained references to methods, constructors, and fields that we could not see. That makes it hard to determine if the bug is in the code you're showing us or in the code you're not showing us. More reading on the subject: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the whole source code, so I'm just guessing here, but...
`newLinkedList` points to an instance of class linkedList1. I suppose in that class you've defined a memober variable called `head`. I assume that variable is initialized to `null`. in the `main` method you're creating instances of `newLinkedList`, one of which is assigned to a *LOCAL* variable `head`. That variable *is not* the same as the variable you've defined in the class, which is the one you're referring to in:

```
Node currentLast = head;
```

Hence, `currentLast` is `null`, which will cause your exception later on.

What you want to do is this: `addLast` should first check whether `head` is `null` or not. if it is, it should assign the passed node to `head`, making it the fist node. If not, it should loop. Disregard the other answer, your loop is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the static variable `head` is null. You are re-initializing a new `head` node in your main method, change it to the static variable `head`. Below is the solution

```
public static void main(String[] args){   
    linkedList1 newLinkedList = new linkedList1(head);
    Node second = newLinkedList.new Node(6,null);
    head = newLinkedList.new Node(5, second);
    Node third = newLinkedList.new Node(8, null);
    newLinkedList.addLast(third);
}
```

Comment: A better fix is to make `head` non-`static`. It really shouldn't be `static` in the first place.

Comment: True that. It shouldn't be static after all.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the problem is because you call the getNextNode method twice in one while loop. Try doing something like this.

```
Node node;
while ((node=currentLast.getNextNode()!=null){
        //do stuff with node
}
```

This helps because now you call getNextNode only once so you won't run into NullPointerExceptions

Comment: Changed it to what you said, still gives an error. really baffling me.